# Would like to put texts side by side inside a DIV

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am looking to achieve the above inside a DIV with something similar coding:

```
<div id="container3" style="position: relative;">
    <div id="left" style="position: absolute; padding-left: 10px;">
        About Company<br>Our Team<br>Careers
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS of the parent DIV which will hold all of the text inside:

```
#container3 {
    vertical align: top;
    width: 80%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: You just got a question answered by many. What are your plans ? Do you have anything you've tried for this so far ?

Comment: I am actually rushing against time. I am trying out some code on my end as well... Sorry couldn't post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something similar to this:

[image]

HTML:

```
<ul class="footer">
    <li class="link">
        Link
    </li>
    <li class="link">
        Link
    </li>
    <li class="link">
        Link
    </li>
    <li class="link">
        Link
    </li>
    <li class="link">
        Link
    </li>
    <li class="link">
        Link
    </li>
    <li class="link">
        Link
    </li>
    <li class="link">
        Link
    </li>
    <li class="link">
        Link
    </li>
    <li class="link">
        Link
    </li>
    <li class="link">
        Link
    </li>
    <li class="link">
        Link
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.footer{
    background-color:#000000;
    padding-left:5px;
}

.link{
    color:#ffffff;
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xU76e/)**

`Alternate Solution`: http://jsfiddle.net/xU76e/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="footer">
    <ul class="footer-links">
        <li class="link">
            Link
        </li>
        <li class="link">
            Link
        </li>
        <li class="link">
            Link
        </li>
        <li class="link">
            Link
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="footer-links">
        <li class="link">
            Link
        </li>
        <li class="link">
            Link
        </li>
        <li class="link">
            Link
        </li>
        <li class="link">
            Link
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="footer-links">
        <li class="link">
            Link
        </li>
        <li class="link">
            Link
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer{
    background-color:#000000;
    overflow:auto;
}

.footer-links{
    padding-left:5px;
    float:left;
    padding:0px 20px;
    list-style:none;
}

.link{
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Thank you... I am completing mine and it's almsot done! But i appreciate your help... very very much

Comment: Added two solutions in this answer..hoping one of them will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
#container3 > div {
float: left;
padding-left: 10px;
/* any additional styling */
}
```

Comment: What if I wanted to make a grid like the image in my question and display links vetically aligned? Sorry I am trying something on my end as well...